# How to set up a Binance WebSocket Connection with Vapor?

Tags: swift, binance, vapor, binance-api-client

I tried setup Binance websocket like this, what do I miss?

```swift
app.get("hello") { req -> EventLoopFuture<String> in
    return WebSocket.connect(to: "wss://stream.binance.com:9443", headers: HTTPHeaders([("binance-api-key", "api-key"), ("binance-api-secret", "api-secret"), ("signature", "dcad576d5d0d9e25ee3fe427b0a50cdf9adec8ec528be05c9f1f7c684ee165f0")]), configuration: .init(), on: req.eventLoop, onUpgrade: { ws in
        return
    }).map({ _ in
        return "done"
    })
}
```

I reaise an error:

```
{
    "error": true,
    "reason": "invalidResponseStatus(HTTPResponseHead { version: HTTP/1.1, status: badRequest, headers: [(\"Date\", \"Sun, 12 Dec 2021 17:41:54 GMT\"), (\"Content-Type\", \"text/plain\"), (\"Content-Length\", \"20\"), (\"Connection\", \"keep-alive\")] })"
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I'm currently trying to connect to a socket but I'm not getting any data.... It's like the connection is immediately being deinitialized.